# What are all the ways in which a gold block can be removed in vanilla Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm developing a skyblock plugin in vanilla Minecraft in which placed gold blocks will generate a certain amount of gold per hour. Naturally, I must keep a list of the placed gold blocks in memory, and remove them from memory when the gold blocks are removed.

What are all the ways in which a gold block can be removed in vanilla Minecraft? Here are the methods I have so far. Have I missed anything?

- Breaking manually with tool/hand
- Breaking from explosions

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but can't you use a pick enchanted with silk touch ?

Comment: @aman207 I think OP has already covered that with 'breaking manually with tool/hand".  He's asking about other ways a gold block could come to no longer be a block in the world.

Comment: @gatherer818 Ah yes, that would make more sense.

Comment: It might be important to consider gold blocks that are pushed via piston

Comment: "developing a plugin" and "vanilla minecraft"? How? Do you mean with commandblocks? In this case, dont call it a plugin. Instead use something like "commandblock-contraption".

Comment: @Mystery he needs to find all vanilla ways to make his non vanilla plugin work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was way overthinking this. Catching all block breaking events is not necessary. One only needs to store the locations of each placed gold block and then check every hour if that location still contains a gold block.

Comment: You may want to make this an edit to your question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that commands are not allowed.

Can players reach the End?

The Ender Dragon has the ability to break blocks. These are just removed and disappear.